# JXLS table formatting

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I have a several tables that are populated through JXLS, I am able to get the output into excel however there is some formatting issue

[JXLS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYDT8.png)

As you can see that I have two parallel tables where the number of rows are varying and since this is something that I am obtaining programatically, I cannot determine how many rows to leave. As a result of which in the tables below formatting is ruined, they should ideally start of from the same row.

I there any way to afix the two tables so that they start from the same row.

Comment: Couldn't determine that based on the number of rows? You could get that programmaticaly and then put some condition allowing you to format the reste

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution through JXLS. Don't want to modify code for every possible situation. Moreover templates are predesigned. Cannot change them as per the data.

Comment: Please raise this issue in jxls tracker and attach an example demonstrating the issue